# How to write an Emscripten shim for a C library

Tags: c, emscripten, shim

How do I write a custom Emscripten shim for a C library? Emscripten bundles shims for certain C libraries such as SDL and OpenAL, but for other libraries you're going to have to roll your own.

By shim I mean, a JavaScript replacement for a C library that the code to be ported depends on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emscripten has some [documentation on the subject](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript), although it's somewhat incomplete at the time of writing.

First of all, you need to write an Emscripten "library" in JavaScript, let's assume the corresponding C library is called Example:

**example.js:**

```
// "use strict";

var LibraryExample = {
    // Internal functions
    $EXAMPLE: {
        internal_func: function () {
        }
    },
    example_initialize: function (arg) {
        EXAMPLE.internal_func()
    }
}

autoAddDeps(LibraryExample, '$EXAMPLE')
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, LibraryExample)
```

Second, you must integrate your **example.js** file into the build, through emcc's *--js-library* option:

```
emcc --js-library shims/example.js -o project.js project.bc
```

Now the function `example_initialize` should be available to the JS code generated by Emscripten, thus replacing the C library dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the JavaScript library in TypeScript then you can use the [npm package emscripten-library-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emscripten-library-decorator). You can then write the library as a class with static functions and export them to asm.js code by adding a decorator `@exportLibrary` to the class.

Functions depending on others need a `@dep` decorator with the other required functions as parameters because otherwise they will likely be removed by Emscripten's dead code elimination, if they're not also directly called from the C or C++ side.

Here's an example from the npm package README:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/emscripten-library-decorator/index.ts" />

function _print(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
}

@exportLibrary
class test {
    @dep(_print)
    static hello() {
        _print('Hello, World!!');
    }

    static foobar = 42;
};
```

There's also a [longer article with more information](http://blog.charto.net/asm-js/Writing-Emscripten-libraries-in-TypeScript/).